# Angular 6/7 Getting Data from API When Returning to Previously Viewed Route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm new to angular and having a bit of trouble.  I want to direct a user to a data entry page where many of the fields are already filled by an api call to the database, by record id.  The user will then edit some of those fields, save the data, and carry on.  This is all working fine.  The problem is that if the user goes off to a different page and does something else, then navigates back to that same URL where they did the initial data entry, the data shown on the page is the data that was originally fetched, not the data that was posted.  I have a router set up, and a resolver to delay loading the page until all the data has been fetched from the api, but the api only seems to get called once, instead of each time the page is loaded.

My resolver:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ProjectVM> {
    let id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.apiService.getProject(id).pipe(
        take(1),
        map(projectVM => {
            if (projectVM) {
                return projectVM;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/projects']);
                return null;
            }
        }))
}
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: { projectVM: ProjectVM }) => {
        this.projectVM = data.projectVM;
    });
}
```

Routing Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/projects', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
    { path: 'projects', component: MyProjectsComponent },
    { path: 'project/:id', component: ProjectOverviewComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', resolve: { projectVM: ProjectResolver } },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        ProjectResolver,
        LeaseResolver,
        ProjectSearchResolver,
        LeaseSearchResolver
                ]  
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The data is posting to the database just fine, but the router doesn't seem to want to call the database more than once per ID.

Comment: What does your route configuration look like? (The part with the resolver?)

Comment: Added the router to the post.

Comment: I have similar code in my app, but without the `onSameUrlNavigation` and `runGuardsAndResolvers`. I know that is somewhat new, so you could try taking that off to see if it matters. Otherwise I don't see anything that looks incorrect. Could you try building a stackblitz that demonstrates the problem (just the problem, not all of your code) so we can see if we can replicate it?

Comment: It looks like the problem came from ASP.NET, not from Angular.  Thanks for double checking my work and verifying that I wasn't going crazy.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  Angular was working just fine.  The problem came from the ASP.NET MVC project that was being called by the API.  .NET appears to cache action result output by default.  I added `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]` as an attribute to all of the methods being called by Angular, and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it. Consider making your answer as the accepted answer to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show in stackblitz. Btw ngOnInit is only called during component initialization. So if you are on same component ngOnInit won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

This is might be because you are navigating back before the edit/create request completed. I resolved after spending 3/4 days on it simply by navigating back when the current request has been completed. See below:

Before resolving:

```
create() {
    this.deptService.addDept(this.dept).subscribe();
    //This line will execute before the above action completed.. 
    this.router.navigate(['department']);
  }
```

After resolving:

```
create() {
    this.deptService.addDept(this.dept).subscribe((data) => {
        //navigate after the request has been completed!
        this.router.navigate(['department']);
      },
      (error) => {
        alert('Error occurred!');
      });
  }
```

Or

```
create() {
    this.deptService.addDept(this.dept).
      toPromise().then(x => {
        //navigate after the request has been completed!
        this.router.navigate(['department']);
      });
  }
```